# Prevent Menu icon from fading on tap

Tags: swiftui

I have the following Menu component:

```swift
        Menu {
            ForEach(self.options, id: \.self) { option in
                Button(action: {
                    self.selected = option
                    self.action(option)
                }) {
                    Text(option))
                }
            }
        }
        .label: {
            Image("menu-image")
        }
```

Everything works fine, but as soon as I tap on the image to open the menu, it is faded out while the drop-down is displayed. How to customise this behaviour to have the image (or any view used as Menu button) **not** fade out?

Comment: Modifying the button with `.animation(nil)` may stop it or just stop the animation toward lower opacity. Not sure, try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe try this. the trick is to make a ZStack. In my example I took a system image... but you can take any image you want.

```
import SwiftUI
struct NonFadingMenuImage: View {
@State private var menuIsShown = false

var body: some View {
    ZStack{
        Menu(content:  {
            Section(header: Text("create options")){
                Text("menu option")
            }
        }, label: {
            Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .padding()
            
        }).onTapGesture {
            menuIsShown = true
        }
        
        if menuIsShown{
            Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .padding()
                .onTapGesture {
                    menuIsShown = false
                }
            
        }
    }
}
}
```